# Create a ranking of data based on the dates and categories of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
 account_id contract_id type    date activated
0   1   AAA Downgrade   2021-01-05
1   1   ADS Original    2020-12-12
2   1   ADGD    Upgrade 2021-02-03
3   1   BB  Winback 2021-05-08
4   1   CC  Upgrade 2021-06-01
5   2   HHA Original    2021-03-05
6   2   HAKD    Downgrade   2021-03-06
7   3   HADSA   Original    2021-05-01
```

I want the following output:

```
 account_id contract_id type    date activated  Renewal Order
0   1   ADS Original    2020-12-12  Original
1   1   AAA Downgrade   2021-01-05  1st
2   1   ADGD    Upgrade 2021-02-03  2nd
3   1   BB  Winback 2021-05-08  Original
4   1   CC  Upgrade 2021-06-01  1st
5   2   HHA Original    2021-03-05  Original
6   2   HAKD    Downgrade   2021-03-06  1st
7   3   HADSA   Original    2021-05-01  Original
```

The column I want to create is "Renewal Order". Each account can have multiple contracts. The condition is based on each account (account_id), the type (only when it is either "Original" or "Winback", and the order in which the contracts are activated (date_activated). The first contract (or tagged as "Original" under the "Type" column) will be identified as "Original" while the succeeding contracts as "1st", "2nd", and so on. The order resets when the contract is tagged as "Winback" under the "Type" column, i.e. it will now be identified as "Original" and the succeeding contracts as "1st", "2nd", and so on (refer to contract_id BB).

I tried the following code but it does not consider the condition on the "Winback":

```
def format_order(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 'Original'
    suffix = ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th'][min(n % 10, 4)]
    if 11 <= (n % 100) <= 13:
        suffix = 'th'
    return str(n) + suffix


df = df.sort_values(['account_id', 'date_activated']).reset_index(drop=True)
# apply
df['Renewal Order'] = df.groupby('account_id').cumcount().apply(format_order)
```

Here's the dictionary of the original dataframe:

```
   {'account_id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 3},
 'contract_id': {0: 'AAA',
  1: 'ADS',
  2: 'ADGD',
  3: 'BB',
  4: 'CC',
  5: 'HHA',
  6: 'HAKD',
  7: 'HADSA'},
 'type': {0: 'Downgrade',
  1: 'Original',
  2: 'Upgrade',
  3: 'Winback',
  4: 'Upgrade',
  5: 'Original',
  6: 'Downgrade',
  7: 'Original'},
 'date activated': {0: Timestamp('2021-01-05 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2020-12-12 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2021-02-03 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2021-05-08 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2021-03-05 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2021-03-06 00:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2021-05-01 00:00:00')}}
```

Here's the dictionary for the result:

```
    {'account_id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 3},
 'contract_id': {0: 'ADS',
  1: 'AAA',
  2: 'ADGD',
  3: 'BB',
  4: 'CC',
  5: 'HHA',
  6: 'HAKD',
  7: 'HADSA'},
 'type': {0: 'Original',
  1: 'Downgrade',
  2: 'Upgrade',
  3: 'Winback',
  4: 'Upgrade',
  5: 'Original',
  6: 'Downgrade',
  7: 'Original'},
 'date activated': {0: Timestamp('2020-12-12 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2021-01-05 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2021-02-03 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2021-05-08 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2021-03-05 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2021-03-06 00:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2021-05-01 00:00:00')},
 'Renewal Order': {0: 'Original',
  1: '1st',
  2: '2nd',
  3: 'Original',
  4: '1st',
  5: 'Original',
  6: '1st',
  7: 'Original'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us just change the `cumcount` result

```
s = df.groupby('account_id').cumcount()
s[df.type=='Winback'] = 0
df['Renewal Order'] = s.apply(format_order)
```

Comment: Hi! I have a problem with the code. It identifies the contract after the "Winback" as "2nd" instead of "1st".

Answer (score 1):

Using @BENY solution:

```
df = df.sort_values(['account_id', 'date activated']).reset_index(drop=True)
s = df.groupby(['account_id',
                (df['type'] == 'Winback').cumsum()
               ]).cumcount() 
df['Renewal Order'] = s.apply(format_order)
```

Output:

```
   account_id contract_id       type date activated Renewal Order
0           1         ADS  Downgrade     2020-12-12      Original
1           1         AAA   Original     2021-01-05           1st
2           1        ADGD    Upgrade     2021-02-03           2nd
3           1          BB    Winback     2021-05-08      Original
4           1          CC    Upgrade     2021-06-01           1st
5           2         HHA   Original     2021-03-05      Original
6           2        HAKD  Downgrade     2021-03-06           1st
7           3       HADSA   Original     2021-05-01      Original
```